# Units/zero divisors in $R[x]$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be the set of integers modulo $9$, $\mathbb{Z}_9$, and define $R[x]$ to be the corresponding polynomial ring. Determine whether $x, 3x, 1 + x$, and $1 + 3x$ are units or zero divisors.

My attempt:

> $3x$ is a zero divisor since $3x \cdot 3 = 9x = 0$ in mod $9$. $1 + 3x$ is a unit since
> \begin{align*}
> (1 + 3x)(1 - 3x) = 1 - 3x + 3x + 9x^2 \equiv 1.  
> \end{align*}

I cannot figure out $x$ and $1 + x$. By trial and error, I believe they are neither units nor zero divisors, but I cannot figure out how to prove it.

REVISED ATTEMPT:

> Consider a non-zero polynomial $p(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \ldots + a_n x^n$ where $a_n \neq 0$ for some $n \geq 0$. Then
> \begin{align*}
> x p(x) & = x (a_0 + a_1 x + \ldots + a_n x_n) \\
> & = a_0 x + a_1 x^2 + \ldots + a_n x^{n+1}.
> \end{align*}
> Since $a_n \neq 0$, $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n + 1$. Since $n \geq 0$, this implies that $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $\geq 1$. Therefore, it cannot equal either $0$ or $1$, so it is neither a zero divisor or a unit.

Comment: Did you mean you can’t figure out $x$ and $1+x$?

Comment: Yes. I fixed it.

Comment: Check that the leading term of $xp(x)$ is always of degree at least $1$ and nonzero, so it cannot be either a unit or a zero divisors. Then try something similar with $1+x$.

Comment: I'm not completely sure how to check that, though. Do I take an arbitrary polynomial $p(x) = a + bx$? I can't decide which degree polynomial to use, and though it doesn't make sense to take anything above degree $1$, I can't articulate why.

Comment: You take an arbitrary polynomial; why would it be of degree 1? *Arbitrary* degree. $p(x) = a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx^n$, with $a_i\in \mathbb{Z}_9$, $a_n\neq 0$.

Comment: I revised my attempt, using your suggestion. How does that look?

Answer (score 2):

What about $1+x$? Let's try multiplying by a nonzero polynomial
$$
(1+x)(a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_nx^n)=
a_0+(a_1+a_0)x+(a_2+a_1)x^2+\dots+(a_n+a_{n-1})x^n+a_nx^{n+1}
$$
If $1+x$ is a unit, we should be able to find
$$
a_n=0,\quad a_n+a_{n-1}=0,\quad\dots,\quad a_1+a_0=0,\quad a_0=1
$$
and you immediately see the contradiction.

Can $1+x$ be a zero divisor? Again not, because we'd need $a_0=0$, so also $a_1=0$ and so on up to $a_n$.

What's the difference between $1+x$ (neither a unit nor a zero divisor) and $1+3x$ (a unit)? That $3x$ is *nilpotent*.

Your attempt for $x$ is good: if $p(x)$ has degree $n\ge0$, then $xp(x)$ has degree $n+1$.

Any time a polynomial $q(x)$ has a unit as its leading term, the degree formula holds $\deg(q(x)p(x))=\deg q(x)+\deg q(x)$. Prove it. This provides a different proof of the fact that $1+x$ is neither a unit nor a zero divisor.